# Affect on credit score if I apply for a card just to get a one time discount

Tags: credit-card, credit-score

I currently have decent credit, but not exceptional due to limited use of credit.  I have two credit cards, one used regularly (and payed off every month) and a backup credit card.

I've run into offers to save 50 dollars (or similar) if I apply for a credit card.  Assuming I check the fine print and the discount can be received without too many restrictions; I'm wondering what the affect would be on my credit score to accept the card just to get the discount.

If I get the card and immediately close it will that be better or worse then getting a card and keeping it open but unused?  How can I compare the affect on my credit to cold hard cash?

Comment: Note that the "credit score" is not the whole story.  For example, recently opened cards (even if closed afterwards) will [cause some banks to reject your application without regard to score](https://www.doctorofcredit.com/chase-524-rule-explained-detail-need-know/#The_Basics).

Comment: If you always pay all your bills, and pay them on time, then you will have a good credit score, period. Why do you care what your exact score will be, unless you are planning to buy a house soon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do this for one card, it will generate a hard pull that will lower your score by a few points.  This is the case even if you close the card immediately afterwards.  For one card it shouldn't be an issue at all, but if you consistently do this with all the multiple offers that you are receiving you will eventually be considered a high risk  when applying for credit.

Regardless, is the $50 really worth all the hassle of maintaining another card?